qemu installed correctly and running but no /dev/kvm on arm64 ubuntu
Hi I have installed the following packages on my ubuntu arm64 machine
qemu-system-aarch64 qemu-system-arm and others.
qemu-kvm service is also running successfully. But there's still no /dev/kvm file on my machine. As a result, I couldn't able to run some docker containers that need /dev/kvm path as a variable. I have heard that /dev/kvm is only for amd64 machines. On arm64 kvm works differently. Is it true? then which path should we define to use kvm accelerator instead of /dev/kvm in case of arm64 machines?
Also dmesg | grep "kvm" shows the below message
[ 0.752048] kernel: kvm [1]: HYP mode not available
[ 2.988506] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization kvm

